# simplify $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}3^j)$

Tags: combinatorics

simplify $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}3^j)$

I'm looking for a hint, I'm not really seeing a direction.

Comment: Your innermost Sum is a GP..after using formula for summation of a GP...Use expansion of $(1+x)^n$ at $x=-1$ and at $x=-3$

Comment: yep i just understood it 2 minutes ago, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{j=0}^k 3^j$ can be simplified with geometric series. Then you see something like $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k 3^k$. There will be some extra factors and terms, but that's the idea. Put in a $1^{n-k}$ and you see a binomial formula.

Comment: could you check my answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}3^j)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(1+3)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-4)^k = (1+(-4))^n=(-3)^n$$

This is the solution I got to. Would be nice if someone can confirm/point out mistakes.

Comment: There is no k choose j

Comment: my bad, i wrote the question wrong. thank you

Comment: This looks correct to me. One good way to see if you made a mistake somewhere would be to check for small values (e.g. $n=0$, $n=1$, etc.) -- if your two sides agree you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

We'll switch the order of the summations, then we'll be using Pascal's formula. Let $ n $ be a positive integer, we have :

\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}3^{j}}}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}3^{j}}}\\ &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{\sum_{k=j}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n-j}{k-j}\binom{n}{j}3^{j}}}\\ &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{j}3^{j}\sum_{k=j}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n-j}{k-j}}}\\ &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{j}3^{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}{\left(-1\right)^{k+j}\binom{n-j}{k}}}\\ &=\left(-3\right)^{n}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{j}3^{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}{\left(-1\right)^{k+j}\binom{n-j}{k}}}\\ &=\left(-3\right)^{n}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{j}\left(-3\right)^{j}\left(1-1\right)^{n-j}}\\ &=\left(-3\right)^{n}\end{aligned}

Comment: I actually got to $(-3)^n$ with a simpler solution, any chance your answer is wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry the question was written wrong, it is fixed now.